# Automating posting of RSS feed to Twitter and FB

Tags: rss, facebook, twitter

How can I take a RSS feed and post it to Twitter and FB account and automate this process? Is this possible? Would appreciate some directions.

Answer (score 2):

http://twitterfeed.com/ should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

twitterfeed is discontinued now. You can use http://tweeps.co to post from rss to twitter now.